# U-Boot error while decompressing gzipped kernel

Tags: u-boot

I have an older embedded device (PHYTEC phyCORE-LPC3250) that runs the ancient U-Boot 1.3.3.

The Linux kernel uImage gets copied to the NAND flash at `0x200000`, then booted with: `nboot 80100000 0 200000;bootm`

This works fine if the uImage is derived from the self-expanding zImage, but according to [this mailing list post](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2013-October/016778.html) it is preferable to have U-Boot perform the decompression itself.

So I have tried creating a uImage that contains a gzipped version of the normal kernel image, but decompression fails:

```
Image Name:   Poky (Yocto Project Reference Di
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
Data Size:    4057248 Bytes =  3.9 MB
Load Address: 80008000
Entry Point:  80008000
Verifying Checksum ... OK
Uncompressing Kernel Image ... Error: inflate() returned -3
GUNZIP: uncompress or overwrite error - must RESET board to recover
```

This scenario is [described in the FAQ](https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/LinuxUncompressingError), which suggests that the problem is running out of RAM. But I have 128 MB of RAM, starting at `0x80000000`, and the uncompressed kernel is only 8 MB.

(I validated that the data in the uImage is in fact gzipped.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First U-Boot copies the uImage from NAND to RAM at the specified address `0x80100000`. Then it unpacks the kernel to the load address specified in the uImage header, `0x80008000`.

Since our kernel is about 8 MB uncompressed, that means the kernel's memory from `0x80008000` to approximately `0x80800000` overlaps where we copied the uImage at `0x80100000`.

If the uImage is not compressed, unpacking the kernel can use `memmove` which handles overlapping address ranges without issue. (If the load address *is* the address where we copied it in RAM, the kernel gets executed in-place.)

But for compressed uImages, if we overwrite the compressed data while decompressing, decompression will obviously fail.